# DynamicResource color not working

Tags: .net, wpf, styles, dynamicresource

I have the following code:

```
<Color x:Key="SelectedColor">Gold</Color>
```

And a TabItem Style that contains the color

```
<VisualState x:Name="Selected">
    <Storyboard>
        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames 
            Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Fill).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[0].(GradientStop.Color)"
            Storyboard.TargetName="InnerRectangle2">
            <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{DynamicResource SelectedColor}"/>
        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
```

It turns out I can't use a `DynamicResource` on an `EasingColorKeyFrame`.
What can I do to achieve my effect?

I need to set the color dynamically, so just swapping `"{DynamicResource SelectedColor}"` with `"{StaticResource SelectedColor}"` is off the table.

I've created a tiny solution to demonstrate the problem - the Selected Tab should be Gold colored, but it's actually transparent, because I guess the VSM can't resolve the color named "`SelectedColor`"

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/10557283/DynamicBug.zip

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10196078/452941

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out a way to do it with layers. Make multiple copies of your object, and then just modify the transparencies like this:

```
<VisualState x:Name="Selected">
    <Storyboard>
        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="InnerRectangleBorder"
                         Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                         To="0"
                         Duration="0:0:0" />

        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="InnerRectangleBorderMouseOver"
                         Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                         To="0"
                         Duration="0:0:0.5" />

        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="InnerRectangleBorderSelected"
                         Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                         To="1"
                         Duration="0:0:1" />
    </Storyboard>
</VisualState>
```

Answer (score 6):

Animations(VSM) are `freezable objects`. As soon as you set a binding on a dependency property of a Freezable, you prevent the Freezable from being frozen.  Thus, the bindings on the Value property of your `EasingColorKeyFrame objects are preventing the storyboards from being frozen.`

**As a way out you can try any these three approaches whichever suits you best -**

- Try declaring the resource as `StaticResource` and use it in your VSM. [StaticResource explanation for VSM](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/9336022f-badb-4b40-a86c-a50ab1a64ba5/)
- What i understand from your code is you want the selected tabItem in golden color. So, as a workaround you can do is have the `two borders` contained in a panel say grid one over other with golden border default `visibility` as collapsed and normal one visible.
  Now, on `selected event` (on property change of IsSelected or whatever aproach) of your tabItem you can `swap the visibility` of two borders giving the same effect. Of course this workaround is specific to this case, for example it only makes sense if the EasingColorKeyFrame key time is 0, otherwise it doesn't give the same visual effect.
- Lastly, if you want to stick to do it through animation, you can achieve this in `code behind`. These posts might proves helpful to you - [Woakaround for dynamicResource in Animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4284672/dynamic-resource-access-fails-in-storyboard), [Animation in code behind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3415094/why-storyboard-value-wouldnt-get-from-a-resource-or-binding) and [Setting foreground with VSM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3644969/problem-setting-foreground-with-visual-state-manager)

Comment: Gold is just the default color, I want it to be dynamically set.  I think this rules out the first two points.  Still thinking about the third.

Answer (score 3):

It's because the VSM types aren't part of the logical tree, so the dynamic resource lookup cannot be resolved.

Comment: @iterationx: use StaticResource.

Comment: @Phil I want to change the colors at runtime

Comment: move EasingColorKeyFrame to resources outside VSM, reference color as dynamic resource and reference EasingColorKeyFrame in ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames as static resources. something like this must work

Comment: @koshdim How can I move EasingColorKeyFrame?  ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames does not have a Value property, usually I would do a Value={StaticResource X}" , but I can't do that in this case?

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is a bit late, but this example worked very well for me regarding assignment of a color using a DynamicResource in a VisualState Storyboard:

```
<VisualState x:Name="PopupOpen">
  <Storyboard>
        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames
               Storyboard.TargetName="rootGrid"
               Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background)">
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.25" Value=" 
            {DynamicResource 
                  BrushIconComboBox_Popup_Open_Background}" />
```