# Change WPF TextBox Foreground color in ControlTemplate

Tags: wpf, controltemplate, foreground

I have Styled textboxes that use a Control Template to set the background color depending on visual state (Mouseover, Disabled, etc).  Code was taken from MS' [TextBox Templates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752068.aspx) page.

What I want to do is also change the Foreground (font) colour depending on the visual state.  For example, on Mouseover, I want to make the text colour stand out, and on Disabled, I want to grey it out

My xaml (I have removed VisualState tags for 'Normal' and 'Disabled' and a couple of <Border.Blah> children of Border):

```
<Color x:Key="EditableControlHiLightColor">Ivory</Color>
<Color x:Key="EditableControlHiLightTextColor">Pink</Color>


<Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
  <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="100" />
  <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="20" />
  <Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
      <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TextBoxBase}">
        <Border Name="Border"
            CornerRadius="4"
            Padding="2"
            BorderThickness="1">
          <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
              <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver" >
                <Storyboard>
                  <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Border" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextBox.Background).Color">
                    <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource EditableControlHiLightColor}" />
                  </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                </Storyboard>
              </VisualState>
            </VisualStateGroup>
          </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
          <ScrollViewer Margin="0" x:Name="PART_ContentHost" />
        </Border>
      </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
</Style>
```

I first tried to add a new <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames> inside the Storyboard tag to alter the Foreground so it looks like:

```
<Storyboard>
  <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Border" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextBox.Background).Color">
    <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource EditableControlHiLightColor}" />
  </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
  <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Border" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextBox.Foreground).Color">
    <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource EditableControlHiLightTextColor}" />
  </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
</Storyboard>
```

but that had no effect - the text colour stays the same.

I figured this was due to the <Border> at the top of the <ControlTemplate>, so I tried to set a <Foreground ... > tag as a child of ControlTemplate.  Visual Studio was having none of that. (*The type Foreground was not found.  Verify that you are not missing an assembly reference and that all referenced assemblies have been built.*)

I've had a look through SO and there seems to be something to do with [properties that are set by template binding that cannot be changed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3644969/problem-setting-foreground-with-visual-state-manager), but in my case it's within the template that I am trying to make the change.

So, how do I change the Foreground (font) colour of a textbox in a control template using visual states?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that we can only change ScrollViewer Foreground by changing TextBox Foreground. To do this you can use Trigger:

```
 <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="Foreground">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <SolidColorBrush Color="{StaticResource ControlDisabledForeground}"/>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsReadOnly" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Foreground">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <SolidColorBrush Color="{StaticResource ControlReadOnlyForeground}"/>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Trigger>
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>
```

You can see full code here:
https://gist.github.com/Javad-Amiry2/5897049